# Resize div to contentEditable iFrame using onkeyup

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've got a div that holds a contenteditable iframe.  The CSS has height set on auto, I've set it up so on keyup the div resizes to the iframe's scroll height.

**I'm able to correctly expand the div based on the content's height, but I am not able to contract the height when removing content from the iframe.**

I've tested grabbing the body scrollHeight, Height height, offsetHeight; but they only return the last largest value.

Any ideas?

Comment: setTimeout might help

Comment: @EL no, re-read what I wrote.  On keyup is the event catcher, which works, it's contracting the size that's not working.  I'm unable to fetch the body's true content height.

Comment: Then maybe getting  scroll heights of iframe?

Comment: @EL that's correct, so I'm trying to retrieve height via body standard height as well as body offsetHeight, but neither return the true height, only the last largest expanded height.

Comment: no. not the body. iframe's scroll  heights.

Comment: @EL no that does not work either.

Comment: @MichaelMikhjian try clientHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by utilizing a constant interval to resize.  I'm not too happy with this option, I'd rather keep it as a onkeyup function, but it seems the dom area doesn't resize instantly, it takes X.X seconds for it to realize via contenteditable sections.